# How to run file-specific commands?

Tags: org-mode

For some org-mode files, I would like to run specific commands when that file is opened for editing. These commands should be written in the heading of the file somewhere near the `#+CONFIG` bits.

E.g in my 'WeeklyReport.org' I would like it to automatically run my function `NavigateToOrCreateThisWeek()`

Is this possible?

As an alternative, I currently have functions that load a file and then do something. But I'd like to instruct the functions to be ran when ever I open that file.

Comment: Try [file local variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables)? especially `eval`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I evaluate elisp in an orgmode file when it is opened?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12938/how-can-i-evaluate-elisp-in-an-orgmode-file-when-it-is-opened)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using eval with Emacs file-specific variables, then any valid lisp function can be specified at the end of the file as shown here:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; eval: (myFunction arg1 arg2)
;; End:
```

If you need variable arguments based on org-mode features, then you can combine the above with [in-buffer settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html#In_002dbuffer-settings) available for org-mode files.

Comment: I found this answer would only work if the Local Variables block were added to the _end_ of the Org Mode file. Using GNU Emacs 26.3.